# How do i get a comma delimited output using the print function in python

Tags: python

I am trying to separate this using "sep" in the print function. But I keep running into some syntax errors. Any ideas?

```
print ((my_loc_dict[a]),(my_env_dict[a]),sep=",")
```

Comment: Python 2 or Python 3?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
When I run your code with constants in place of the variables, it works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe like this?

```
print(a, ',' ,b)
```

Comment: You the man! Thanks @Astrom, i knew it had to be something simple.

Comment: feel free to upvote and accept one of the answer, tks!

Answer (score 0):

Or if you don't want to use the cold comma each time you could do something like that :

```
myListOfValues = ['test', 'other','yet']
print(','.join(myListOfValues))
```

Comment: I'll give this a shot, thanks!